# Unexpected behavior in R with the cat command in R

Tags: r

I'm seeing behavior I don't expect with the cat commands and flush.console() in RGui 2.12.0 (but not Rterm) for Windows.  I wanted to see whether it was a problem with my system (or a known behavior) before reporting it as a bug.  Specifically I'm seeing strange UNICODE looking characters as it iterates through.  Please forgive the use of the huge rnorm() I couldn't figure out how to slow execution in an established way.

```
for (i in 1:100) {cat(i,"\r");flush.console();rnorm(1000000)}

R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: `n <- 2.5; Sys.sleep(n)` is a cheaper way to delay. The `time` argument is in seconds and can be fractional, eg `Sys.sleep(0.1)` would sleep for (approximately) 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Where do you see strange characters? Always in the same place? Or in different places each time you try this? Have you tried using \n instead of \r for end-of-line?

Comment: I use \r to update while I am in long loops to keep track of where I am and assure myself progress is being made (it is similar to how the base text progress bar works).  I don't like using \n because it spams interesting stuff off my screen.  Interestingly the error does not occur with \n.

Comment: The characters always show up where I'd expect the catted text to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the RGui and the devs claim it will be fixed in the next minor release of 2.12.

Answer (score 2):

It worked as you would expect under R-2.10.0, which is the previous version of R installed in my seldom-used Windows machine. ;-)

I would say report it, but I would just send it to R-devel as "unexpected behavior" as you did here.  Make sure to check against the latest daily build before reporting it, since it may have already been fixed.